# /sdcard/alt_autocycle - what is it?

Tags: file-system

I have an empty folder called `/sdcard/alt_autocycle`.

1. What creates it?
2. What is it used for?
3. Can I delete it?

Comment: Are you using a Motorola device? This seems to be related only to Motorola devices, per the threads across the forums on Internet.

Comment: Yes, I am. I searched just now but couldn't find the purpose of the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This folder is created by CQA-Test. It has a service called com.motorola.motocit.alt.altautocycle